# Count work for Merge_Sort Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, count, global-variables, mergesort

All, I would like to count how close an array is being sorted by using Merge Sort Algorithm. I am able to use Merge Sort to arrange the array but I have trouble to keep counting how many inversion I need during the process.

For example, when input [9,4,8,3], I want to get the output [3,4,8,9] and 4 inversions. The definition of inversion is: if b in B , c in C and we have b>c then inversion is needed (the order of B,C matter). First, I will get two parts ([4,9],1) and ([3,8],1) which indicate one inversion individually. Then, when they merge again, there are another two inversions: choosing 3 instead of 4, choosing 8 instead of 9.

My main question might not relate to the algorithm itself. It is about how to keep one of my variable evolve within function loop of a function. (I have using Merge_Sort function within Merge_Sort function)

```
def Merge_Sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    if n==1:
        if not 'total_rev' in vars():            
            total_rev = 0
        else:
            total_rev += rev_ind
    return a , total_rev
    else:
        m = math.floor(n/2)
        b , rev_ind_b = Merge_Sort(a[:m])
        if not 'total_rev' in vars():
            total_rev = 0
        else:
            total_rev += rev_ind_b
        c , rev_ind_c = Merge_Sort(a[m:])
        if not 'total_rev' in vars():
            total_rev = 0
        else:
            total_rev += rev_ind_c      
        a_sort , rev_ind = Merge(b,c)
        if not 'total_rev' in vars():
            total_rev = 0
            total_rev += rev_ind
        else :
            total_rev += rev_ind
        return a_sort , total_rev

def Merge(b,c):
    p = len(b)
    q = len(c)
    d = []
    reverse_ind = 0
    while len(b)!=0 or len(c)!=0 :
        if (len(b)*len(c) != 0) :
            b0 = b[0]
            c0 = c[0]
            if b0 <= c0 :
                d.append(b0)
                b.remove(b[0])
            else :
                reverse_ind += 1
                d.append(c0)
                c.remove(c[0])
        else :
            d.extend(b)
            b=[]
            d.extend(c)
            c=[]
    return d,reverse_ind
```

The Merge function can work well. The only question is I cannot keep the variable "total_inv" update as I wish. I try to define "total_inv" whenever it is not defined. Not sure if it is a good way because it made my code messy. I also try to use global variable but it cannot work well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler than that:

- when at the deepest recursion level (`n==1`) just return 0 for the number of swaps. The logic is that you should return the number of swaps for the list *as it is* at that recursion level, without any consideration of what the larger list may be. So when `n==1` your list has one value, which obviously does not need swapping.
- In other cases, just add up the counts you get from the recursive calls. That way they will increase when bubbling back up the recursion tree.

Here is the adapted code for `Merge_Sort`:

```
def Merge_Sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    if n==1:
        return a, 0 # at deepest recursion always return 0 for the number of swaps
    else:
        m = n//2 # use integer division; you don't need `math.floor`
        b , rev_ind_b = Merge_Sort(a[:m])
        c , rev_ind_c = Merge_Sort(a[m:])
        a_sort , rev_ind = Merge(b,c)
        return a_sort , rev_ind_b + rev_ind_c + rev_ind # add the numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my blindness. I do not need to worry about which layer I was in. I just need to output the reversion from three sources no matter which layer it is. Thank you!